# Pygame window not receiving keyboard events on Mac

Tags: python, ios, macos, pygame, osx-elcapitan

I am running this very simple tutorial on Pygame:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xh4SV3kF-zk

I can't get keyboard events to be recognised by the game window. I have read a number of similar questions about this, but the answers don't seem right for Macs.

I am using miniconda and it might be that I need to quit the virtualenvironment? I don't understand how to do that tho. Or maybe I need to set the focus to my window - but I don't know how to do that either. This must be an issue lots of people are having on Macs running El Capitan. My Mac is too old to upgrade properly to Sierra. Is there a way to get the keyboard input to work?

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

display_width = 1200
display_height = 800

black = (0, 0, 0)
white = (255, 255, 255)
red = (255, 0, 0)
green = (0, 255, 0)
blue = (0, 0, 255)


gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width, display_height))
pygame.display.set_caption('A Bit Racey')
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

speederImg = pygame.image.load('speeder.png')

def speeder(x, y):
    gameDisplay.blit(speederImg, (x, y))

x = (display_width * 0.4)
y = (display_height * 0.2)

x_change = 0

crashed = False

while not crashed:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            crashed = True

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                x_change = -5
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                x_change = 5

        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                x_change = 0

    x += x_change

    gameDisplay.fill(white)
    speeder(x, y)
        # print(event)


    pygame.display.update()

    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Comment: it has to be `K_RIGHT` and `K_LEFT`, not `K-RIGHT`, `K-LEFT`. You should see error message when you run it in console/terminal. See other [key constants](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html) in official documentation.

Comment: watch video again - you see `K_LEFT`, not `K-LEFT` - [moment in video](https://youtu.be/xh4SV3kF-zk?t=284)

Comment: That's a good point, but my issue doesn't go away. When I launch from the terminal I see the keyboard input in the terminal, but my sprite doesn't move

Comment: what if you first click on pygame window ? still nothing ? I don't use Mac so I can't help more.

Comment: Yeah nothing :( after frantic googling it turns out it's something to do with the conda virtualenv - problem solved in the end via pygame git

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For anybody else trying to run from the terminal using Python3 on a Mac, it seems the problem is the window focus. To get it to run properly instead of  typing:

```
python mygame.py
```

type instead:

```
pythonw mygame.py
```

See https://github.com/pygame/pygame/issues/359 for further info

Comment: For me, this just leads to my PyGame window being completely blank.